# Why when I write utf8 characters in mariadb it shows the '> prompt?

Tags: windows, utf-8, mariadb, xampp

I have been having some problems with the character set in windows and mariadb, I discovered that my windows terminal uses cp850 and when I insert the character 'ñ' in mariadb on windows terminal it saves the character '\xA2' instead of the utf8 \x{C3B1}.

#### Other details

| OS | Program | Terminal | Shell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 11 Home x86_64 | MariaDB through XAMPP | Windows Terminal | Command Prompt |

After some investigation I found that to use the full system on UTF8 I need to change the region settings to enable the 'Beta: UTF8..' option but that bring other problem. When I enter the query:
`SELECT 'ñ';` mariadb shows the "'>" prompt, so I need to close an *unopened* quotation mark and put again the semicolon, and when that is done and I press enter mariadb doesn't show anything but only a new line inside the table. (this behavior is the same with 'áéíóú' characters)

I was expecting that the query `SELECT 'ñ'` shows the 'ñ' as is, and I want to use utf8 on mariadb shell (So I need that `SELECT HEX('ñ')` returns 'C3B1') I really searched for a solution but I cant find anything so how can I do that?

And sorry for my bad english.

PS: I've also tried to force the client collation to utf8mb4 but also it doesn't work, it keeps me showing the '> prompt when I type the first query on this question.

Comment: does `chcp 65001` in the terminal before starting the client help?  (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654 makes it sound like the Beta: UTF8 option makes this the default, so maybe not)

Comment: Yes, it does, I checked it with chcp

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26713 fixed in 10.8. Xampp has an ancient version